# Chrome suggests password for Angular Material datepicker

Tags: angular, google-chrome, angular-material, datepicker

Why is Chrome suggesting a password for this datepicker? How do I stop it?

[image: password]

**HTML**

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Start date</mat-label>
    <input type="text" matInput [formControl]="startDate" [matDatepicker]="picker">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

**TS**

```
startDate = new FormControl();
```

There are only 2 inputs on the screen
[image]

Comment: try remove the type="text"

Comment: Makes no difference

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried autocomplete="off" ? or remove type="text" (that one is not needed on mat datepickers)

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Start date</mat-label>
    <input matInput autocomplete="off" [formControl]="startDate" [matDatepicker]="picker">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: try removing type="text" as the guy said above

Comment: Also makes no difference

Comment: I've got exactly the same code in one of my projects and it's working fine, but I'm using formControlName="..." instead of [formControl]="...", also If the input is not editable try adding readonly attribute as well.

Answer (score 0):

*autocomplete="off"* didn't work for me

[image: Code before fix it]

So, to fix this, just add `readonly` to your input

[image: adding readonly to input]

And that's it

[image: Fixed code]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: User should be allowed to type in a date. The issue magically resolved itself for me though...

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
But I noticed it happens only when serving the app in development mode, reloading again and again the same page, as I have a dev-skipping of the authentication that caches the auth header.
By the way sounds defintively a Chrome problem, that falls in confusion.
I hope this observation (not conclusive, in trueth), may help someone.

Comment: A "partial answer" is possible, but it would be required to at least provide a solution for a part of the problem. So if I do not miss something here, this should be deleted to avoid being flagged as "not an answer". (Sorry for the frustration you might feel for the little reputation gap until the commenting privilege....)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after fidgeting with it my problem was the following. I had two datepickers next to each other with their own `<input>` element. Somehow this makes the browser think this is a 'password and validate password' field. To solve this i gave the two inputs their own id e.g. `<input id='datepicker1'  />` and <`input id='datepicker2' />`